AWS Log Insight - Combine Time Series Graphs into a single graph
I'm pretty new to AWS log insights and I've been having problems with plotting several data points over a single graph. Essentially, I have logs that have two fields in question I'd like to us, the first being gameName and the other is connections (current connections).
The goal: I want to have a single timeline graph that shows the average connections to each game every 5 minutes. Plus a total sum of all games connections over time.
Current situation: I have 4 graphs each with a query looking like this. Each query varies by an incrementing game name.
fields @timestamp, connections | filter gameName = "game1" | stats avg(connections) by bin(5m)
Help would be greatly appreciated and thank you for your time.
